# XMLize Stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, metaprogramming, metadata

I want to write a stored procedure with XML(?) in comments.

```
/* <Description>Valid People</Description>
*/
create procedure ValidPeople
as
select 
  /*<Field><Name>Birthday<Name>
      <MinValue>1950-01-01</MinValue>
      <MaxValue>2012-01-01</MaxValue>
      <Sql><![CDATA[*/
  case when not Birthday between '1950-01-01' and '2012-01-01' 
    then Birthday end as Birthday,
  --]]></Sql></Field>
  ....
from 
-- <TableSource>
  ....
-- </TableSource>
```

So I can generate the report of validation rules from the comments for end users. Or let end user modify the rules and let the machine regenerate the stored procedure/comments.

Is there any tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Extended Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx) [to document](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/towards-the-self-documenting-sql-server-database/) your stored procedures (and possibly other objects, like tables, columns, indexes, etc.).

There are tools [available](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/) which can build a database documentation (much like API docs known from Java or .NET) based on that information. Also, the information will be stored as "real" meta data in the database, not just as comments.

Note that extended properties, well the 'MS_Description' property to be precise, is basically only a string. So on one side it is pretty basic, compared to what you *could* achieve with special XML-tags, on the other hand it is pretty flexible, as there are no real limits what to put into the string.

Comment: Sounds good. However some of the rules may be not applied to one table but multiple tables.